# Entity Framework migrations and refactor model into separate project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I started out with an Asp.net MVC project with Entity Framework code first and migrations enabled. Using the standard template I got my model in the same project as the rest of the web site. Now I want to re-use my model in another project, but cannot find a step-by-step recipe for how to move the model and all migrations history, into a separate project. My biggest concerns are that the database comes out of sync with my model, or data in the database is lost. Maybe it's nothing to be afraid of, but I'll be happy if anyone can share their experience!

Comment: what have you tried?  I have done it before so I will try to dig up what I did

Answer (score 1):

Ok when you have migrations turned on you can move your context, the associated entities and the migration configurations to a new project no problem.  If you leave all of the namespaces as is you should not need to change anything.  This is because the key for the migration history in the database is based on the namespace + class of the migration configuration file.  For example in my web application I have migrations at

```
CodeMigrations.Migrations
```

so the ContextKey in the __MigrationHistory table ends up being

```
CodeMigrations.Migrations.Configuration
```

if I move this code to a new project and leave the namespaces as is nothing will need to be changed, however if I want the namespaces to be updated to reflect the new base namespace of the new project I would need to update the rows in __MigrationHistory table, changing the ContextKey to the new name.

for example if I moved mine from a web project named CodeMigrations to a project called CodeMigrations.Model I would need to update the __MigrationHistory table as follows:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] 
   SET 
    [ContextKey] = 'CodeMigrations.Model.Migrations.Configuration'
 WHERE 
    [ContextKey] = 'CodeMigrations.Migrations.Configuration'
```

after doing this the migration history should be associated to the new project now